# How to implement gmail api on xamarin.android project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

How to implement `gmail api` on `xamarin.android` project?. Please help me with example, if possible. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is a developer documentation available for the same.

I am not sure If it will help. You can go through it. Sample is also available. I'll try it my self and will let you know

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services%5CSigninQuickstart/